# Spring, Angular.js 400 Bad Request

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, http-status-code-400

I'm having a hard time figuring out why this request encounter 400 BAD request :

```
{
email: "ccc@gmail.com"
lastfmUsername: "bluecun"
password: "$2a$10$if246VMeosRCNJibodEhueXGyQNiAHeJd3KVHi7WedjByECYeXO5."
username: "bluecun"
}
```

Here is my model and controller code :

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String lastfmUsername;
    private String email;
    private String password;
...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    void register(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
        semanticGraphDao.saveUser(user);
    }
```

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check if you JSON is wellformed, which means: properties surrounded by quotes and a colon between each property, for example:

```json
{
  "email": "ccc@gmail.com",
  "lastfmUsername": "bluecun",
  "password": "$2a$10$if246VMeosRCNJibodEhueXGyQNiAHeJd3KVHi7WedjByECYeXO5.",
  "username": "bluecun"
}
```

On the top of that, check the constructor of your User class. It must have a default constructor:

```java
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String lastfmUsername;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public User() {
      
    }
    
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

And finally, check Spring boot logs - probably it is showing some kind of exception from Jackson, which will guide you on how to solve the mapping issue.

Comment: It's because I don't have default constructor. Thanks a lot!